# Slow to update the clock on startup

Tags: 17.10, clock

When I start Ubuntu 17.10, it's slow to synchronize the clock on the top of the screen. It stays at the last time I had when I suspend the last time and it updates after some minutes.

The time is automatically synchronized through the Internet.

Comment: "When I start.." conflicts with "when I suspend". Time/Date update depends on your internet connection being UP. Does clock sync take longer than that?

Comment: Yes. I can go on the internet before the synchronization